# Few unclear things about Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am finding the Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract class quite insufficient for my application but maybe I am just not aware of some methods or helpers in Zend Framework. Few things I am not able to do with the request object. First I get it like this in a controller action:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

Now I want to get a GET or POST parameter but it is not possible. Only thing I can do is:

```
$foo = $request->getParam('foo');
```

But I want to specifically get the parameter only from POST or GET (without having to use $_GET and $_POST arrays). Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract searches both POST and GET which is not very useful as usually you know exactly from where you want to get the parameter from.

How can I get raw POST data?

How can I get raw PUT data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to chain off of getRequest(), like so:

```
$postUsername = $this->getRequest()->getPost('username');

// Get All Post data
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Have a look at Zend_Controller_Request_Http, which extends the abstract class. As far as PUT data, I see a method to tell if the request was PUT around line 865 of the http controller.

Comment: Similarly, if you want to read JSON that is in the content body, you'd use `->getRawBody()` :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use it like this. Without a chain in a controller. Because there is a protected method inside the Zend_Controller_Action wich do this for you.

```
$this->_getAllParams();
$this->_getParam($paramName,$default);
```